# MongoClient connection from Java is throwing SSL Handshake exception when using DNS seed list connection format

Tags: java, mongodb, ssl, synchronization

I am using `mongoclient` in my plain Java application project using Gradle with the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'
    implementation group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongodb-driver-sync', version: '4.9.0'
    implementation group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongodb-driver-reactivestreams', version: '4.9.1'
    implementation('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.2')
    implementation group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version: '0.7.5'
}
```

When I use the standard connection string format, the application is able to connect without any problems. However, when I try to use a DNS Seed list connection string `(mongodb+srv)` because the production URL is in that format and I do not have the standard URL, I get an error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake}, caused by {java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly}}]
```

The code snippet that is causing the problem is:

```java
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                    .applyToSslSettings(builder -> {
                        builder.enabled(true);
                        builder.invalidHostNameAllowed(true);
                    })
                    .applyToSocketSettings(builder -> {
                        builder.connectTimeout(6000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                        builder.readTimeout(6000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    })
                    .build();
com.mongodb.client.MongoClient blockingMongoClient = com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.create(settings);
            com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase db = blockingMongoClient.getDatabase(Objects.requireNonNull(connectionString.getDatabase()));
            com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection<Document> allUsers = db.getCollection("name of collection");
            LOGGER.info("total number of : " +allUsers.countDocuments());
```

The connection string that I am passing in the above code looks like:

```
mongodb+srv://username:password@host/dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Below is my SSL Handshake report when I debug:

```
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.1",
  "random"              : "32 36 C7 96 66 7C 61 64 DA A1 5B 2E F3 A2 EF B5 D8 B9 A4 6A 5C 2F 9E 3A 24 0D 5A 22 EA 2E 95 45",
  "session id"          : "",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00A), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC009), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0039), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0038), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0033), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0032), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC005), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00F), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC004), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC00E), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F), TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV(0x00FF)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=localhost
    },
    "status_request (5)": {
      "certificate status type": ocsp
      "OCSP status request": {
        "responder_id": <empty>
        "request extensions": {
          <empty>
        }
      }
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [x25519, secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, x448, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "status_request_v2 (17)": {
      "cert status request": {
        "certificate status type": ocsp_multi
        "OCSP status request": {
          "responder_id": <empty>
          "request extensions": {
            <empty>
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.1]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|cluster-ClusterId{value='648d7ae45252df58e9fd0c8d', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017|2023-06-17 14:51:08.694 IST|ClientHello.java:642|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.1",
  "random"              : "5D 3A 7F C2 75 40 D3 7F EA 6F 14 DD 0B 96 DA 5D E4 8E C0 1E AA 69 24 D3 BE 5C 23 FE B9 0D CF D7",
  "session id"          : "",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00A), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC009), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0039), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0038), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0033), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0032), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC005), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00F), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC004), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC00E), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F), TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV(0x00FF)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=localhost
    },
    "status_request (5)": {
      "certificate status type": ocsp
      "OCSP status request": {
        "responder_id": <empty>
        "request extensions": {
          <empty>
        }
      }
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [x25519, secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, x448, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "status_request_v2 (17)": {
      "cert status request": {
        "certificate status type": ocsp_multi
        "OCSP status request": {
          "responder_id": <empty>
          "request extensions": {
            <empty>
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.1]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|11|cluster-ClusterId{value='648d7ae45252df58e9fd0c8d', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017|2023-06-17 14:51:08.696 IST|TransportContext.java:345|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Couldn't kickstart handshaking (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1696)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1514)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:921)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1291)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:102)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:577)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:411)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:357)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:102)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:129)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.startHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:77)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:206)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:199)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:159)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
  Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:483)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)
    ... 16 more}

)
```

Comment: Please suggest solutions, it will be of great help.

Comment: I think `mongodb+srv` is used only when you connect to MongoDB Atlas (MongoDB Cloud service) but you connect to your local host